# paginator function not working in django?

Tags: django, django-pagination, django-viewflow

My issue is that i want to retrieve only 6 objects per page but its showing all 10 per page

**my view**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        entry = Entry.objects.all().order_by('date_added')
        # top_rated = Entry.objects.annotate(
        #     no_of_likes=Count('likes')).order_by('-no_of_likes')[:2]
        pages = Paginator(entry, 6)

        if request.GET.get('page'):
            print('executed')
            page_num = request.GET.get('page')
            pages = pages.page(page_num)

        entries = pages.object_list
    print(len(entries))
    return render(request, 'base/base.html', {'entries': entries,
                                              'pages': pages})
```

Comment: Are you using `entries` or `pages` in the template to render the data? How are you checking that it is returning 10 per page?

Comment: i am returning pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written the code in a fashion with redundant / incomplete (unhandled) checks and assigning different objects to the same variable, resulting in the problem you see. Basically what is happening is that your condition `if request.GET.get('page'):` evaluates to `False` likely because `page` is not present in the query string. This means `entries = pages.object_list` gives you your complete queryset.

Instead try something like follows:

```py
def home(request):
    entry = Entry.objects.all().order_by('date_added')
    pages = Paginator(entry, 6)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    entries = page.object_list
    return render(request, 'base/base.html', {'entries': entries, 'page': page})
```